# how to set a input text as required pysimplegui

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I have a layout and an input text and I want the input text don't be left blank
I have searched all PySimpleGUI  documentation but didn't see how I am able to set an input text as required

here is my code

```
layout = [[sg.Text('enter your license code')],
              [sg.InputText()], # I wan't this input to be required
              [sg.Submit('OK'), sg.Cancel('Cancel')]]
    window = sg.Window('invalid License', layout, icon="logo.ico")
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == 'Cancel' or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break  # exit button clicked
    window.close()
    license_input = values[0]
    read_configs('license.txt')
    lic = "license.txt"
    with open(lic, 'r+') as f:
        text = f.read()
        text = re.sub(license_code, license_input, text)
        f.seek(0)
        f.write(text)
        f.truncate()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A license_code required for a popup window

- 'Cancel' button not necessary and removed
- 'Close' button of window disabled by `enable_close_attempted_event=True` and `sg.WINDOW_CLOSE_ATTEMPTED_EVENT` not handled, or it will destroy window first when 'Close' button clicked.
- Read and return the current value of the input element by method `get`, or by using `values[element]` if not 'Close' button of window event.
- Break event loop only when value of input element not null string.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

layout = [
    [sg.Text('enter your license code')],
    [sg.InputText(key='-INPUT-')],
    [sg.Submit('OK')],
]
window = sg.Window('invalid License',
    layout,
    #icon="logo.ico",
    enable_close_attempted_event=True)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    print(event, values)
    license_code = window['-INPUT-'].get().strip()
    if event == 'OK' and license_code:
        break

window.close()
print(license_code)
```

Comment: is reading and writing to the license file my problem is when the user left it blank it will remove the old value and the regex function fail next time user tries to input license